# Testing DAO file with junit +spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, dao

I'm trying to test a DAO file with junit. Is there a way to compare a same query that was performed with 2 different ways?

Does junit supplies a mechanism that uses in two ways to access the DB?

Comment: Compare queries in term of performance? Result? Why don't you compare results yourself?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue that woul dtake away the point of doing automated unit testing, and in this case integration testing

Comment: If the two ways lives in two different methods in DAO. You can just compare nano-time taken to test each method with exact same test data.

Comment: What I meant is : I'm looking for a junit object/mechanism that i can use to perform the same query - Kind of assert method (that also perform the query by her self!) to results of the query. Thank you for responding!

Comment: What is the pass/fail scenario for this?

Answer (score 1):

there are many different was to perform asserts on data using spring and junit .
Here is a starting point :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext-test.xml"})
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseIntegration {
```

Then your test classes can extend that and just use the dao as normal, and perform asserts on any data.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the results of the query using the methods in Assert class

Comment: Hi,I'm looking for more of that. A way to perform same query AND comparing the results.Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0):

To test DAOs you can use [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/)

Comment: Hi, I prefer f(for now) to test the DAO's on the same DB. Thank you for responding!